# How to pass a string that contains single and double quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string variable called `name`. `name` contains the string `14'6"`. I'm trying to pass `name` to a function. I'm trying to add an `onclick` to a tablerow this like this:

```
$("#trID").attr('onclick', 'testFunction(' + name + ')');
```

I tried using the escape character to achieve this, however I didn't get this to work because the string contains both a single quote (`'`) and a double quote (`"`).

Is there a way I can pass thing string in to a function or do I have to change the string completely?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-append-both-single-and-double-quotes-in-same-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you need to escape the single/double quotes within the `name` string. To do that you could use a regex:

```
name = name.replace(/([\""|\''])/g, '\\$1');
$("#trID").attr('onclick', 'testFunction(' + name + ')');
```

However it should be noted that using inline event handlers, ie. the `onclick` attribute in your example, is not good practice. You should use unobtrusive event handlers instead.

As you've already included jQuery in the page it would be achieved with an event handler and a `data` attribute, like this:

```js
let $div = $("#trID").on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('foo'));
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $div.data('foo', (new Date()).getTime());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trID" data-foo="14'6"">Click me to display value</div>
<button>Click me to change value</button>
```

Comment: I worry that OP doesn't have enough knowledge about javascript fundamental. And what you mention is regex which is an intermediate knowledge

Comment: @Tân not sure what your point is there? Don't introduce an idea to someone who doesn't already know about it? That's the exact opposite of learning new skills.

Comment: Sorry, I just worry about it. I mean regex is not easy to learn for beginner.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you @RoryMcCrossan! Do you mind briefly explaining why the inline event handlers is not good practice?

Comment: @Tân what are you worried aobut?

Comment: @GreenSaber sure, here's an example which covers it better than I can in a comment :) https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Answer (score 0):

Try the string template of javascript

```
$("#trID").attr('onclick', `testFunction(${name})`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON as proxy since its array syntax is based on JavaScript and [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) can cope with JSON fragments (such a standalone string):

```js
function testFunction(param){
    console.log(param);
}
var rawName = "one\n\"two\"\n'three'\nfour";
var encodedName = JSON.stringify(rawName);
console.log(rawName, encodedName);
$("#trID").attr('onclick', 'testFunction(' + encodedName + ')');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trID">Click Me!</button>
```

It's worth noting anyway that you don't need it in the first place. Dynamically generated code is hard. Since you're using jQuery, a cleaner way would be:

```js
function testFunction(param){
    console.log(param);
}
var name = "one\n\"two\"\n'three'\nfour";
$("#trID").on('click', function() {
    testFunction(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trID">Click Me!</button>
```